# Como cargar datos del usuario en un campo select con ngFor?

Tags: firebase, angularjs-2.0

mi problema es el siguiente: 
tengo dos arrays en firebase 
el de categoría :

```js
{
 categorias {
            -KjsSKDoGxOoCJPNWmC6
              {
                id:0,
                nombre:"nombre de la categoria" 
              }
}
```

y el del usuario que guarda una categoría :

```js
subvencionEscolar
  {
      adquisicionBienesMueblesInmuebles
          {
              -KjhktCmLOpecm3yWk0b
                  {
                    id:0,
                    nombre:"nombre x",
                    detail: 
                      {
                        categoria:"categoria que quiero comparar", 
                        fechadoc: "etc",
                        fechapag: "etc",
                        montodecl: "etc"
                      }
                  },
                  ...{}
          }
  }
```

Y necesito cargar este select con la categoría que tiene el usuario y además que contenga las demás categorías que existen 
Este es el select que tengo actualmente, el cual muestra todas las categorías :

          {{cat.nombre}}

esto es lo que me gustaría realizar:

```html
<select name="" >
  <option  value="0" selected> categoria que contiene el usuario </option>
  <option> resto de categorias </option>
  ...
  </select>
```

no se me ocurren mas maneras de resolver el problema, he buscado mucho pero no he encontrado solución :c

Comment: ey no te entiendo bien el problema, quizas deberias añadir un plunkr con codigo y escribir de otra forma tu pregunta...

Comment: replanteare la pregunta enseguida

Comment: Ahora creo que entiendo mejor, mi duda es, dices que quieres enseñar "las dos categorías" todas y la del usuario, pero si enseñas todas, también incluye la seleccionada. Entonces lo que haría sería ponerle el selected a aquella que el usario tenga, haciendo una comprobación.

Comment: si , exacto, pero como la hago? intenté con un ngIf pero me decia que no podía usar dos ng en un mismo campo, el select lo itero con ngFor

Comment: *ngFor='let cat of categories'
[attr.selected]="person.category === cat ? true : null"